# how to order number type string

Tags: sql, laravel

I get

1,
10,
11,
2,
3-1,
3-2,
4,
5,
etc..

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: _Number type string._ Can you kindly elaborate? Are you saying that you have `integer` data in `char` column

Answer (score 0):

insert it to array, then using a sort function.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Answer (score -1):

Use the following format:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC
```

ASC for ascending and DESC for descending order.

Comment: This code is for sql database only. If you bring the data from proper way from your database then you dont have to worry about it later.